# CakePHP 3.0 Custom Event Implementation

Tags: php, cakephp, observer-pattern, cakephp-3.0

I was testing out the Events System on CakePHP v3.0.0-RC2 for my project purposes. I first have to apologise for the long text.

Basically I created a users table with fields id, name, and surname. I then created another table called user_statistics that tallies number of user creations per month. Below is the function that saves a user, create an event for the UserStatistics table object and then finally dispatch the event.

```
use Cake\Event\Event;
class UsersTable extends Table
{
  //Other code
   public function createUser($user)
   {
      if( $this->save( $user )){

        $event = new Event('Model.User.afterPlace', $this, array( 
           'user' => $user 
          ));

        $this->eventManager()->dispatch( $event );

        return true;
       }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

This functions does what its expected - partially so - as it does not seem to dispatch the event but only save the user data. Perhaps the issue lies with the UserStatistics table object. Below is a code snippet of how I have implemented the function that handles tallying of users.

```
use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;

class UserStatistics extends Table implements EventListenerInterface
{
   //Code ommitted for in account of relevence

    public function tallyUsers( $event )
    {
       $data = array();
       if(!empty($event->subject()->user)){

          $date = date('Y-m-d');

          // Check existing record of today 
          $record = $this->find()->where(array('date' => $date));

          if(empty($record)){

             //Insert new record if none exist for the current date
             $data = array(
               'date' => $date,
               'count' => 1
             );
           }else{

             //Update record if date exist by incerementi count field by one
             $count = (int) $record->count + 1;

             $data = array(
                'id' => $record->id,
                'date' => $date,
                'count' => $count
               );
           }

          if($this->save($data))
            return true;
          else
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

After this I had a little misunderstanding as to where I am suppose to register the UserStatistics such that its able to observe the User object. Ofcourse I have implemented the implementedEvents() method on my UserStatistics table object (see below):

```
public function implementedEvents()
{
   return array(
      'Model.User.afterPlace' => 'tallyUsers'
    );
}
```

I figured out that I should register my observer(UserStatistics) inside the UsersController. Below is how I went about doing it:

```
...
publiv function add()
{
   if($this->request->is('post')){

      $this->loadModel('UserStatistics');
      $this->Users->eventManager()->on( $this->UserStatistics );

      if($this->Users->createUser( $user )){
        ....
      }
   }
}
```

Question(s):

1. How can I access the array user passed on the Users table object i.e. array( 'user' => $user )?
2. What does the return true or false suppose to do inside the createUser method on Users table object?
3. Did I pass my observer object on my subject model inside the controller?
4. Should my UserStatistics tallUsers() method return anything?

Please help me understand as I couldnt find clear readings on this subject from the doc itself or any other place.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the two table objects talking to each other. The user statistics table is updated with a record each and everytime a new user is created by the users object which in our case is our subject.

I have suffered so many exception in order to get it to work. Basically I had to enforce a primary key because it couldnt create a new entity without an id. I want to be able to create new records when no records exist for that particular month else update the count field if a record does exist. So the problem is nowhere else but on the code below:

```
public function update( $event )
{
  if(!empty( $event->data)){

    // find current month's record
     if( empty( $record )){
       //Create a new row
       $entity = new \App\Model\Entity\UserStatistic(['id' => 1, 'date' => $date, 'count' => 1]);
       $update = $this->save($entity);
     }else{
       $entity = new \App\Model\Entity\UserStatistic(['id' => $record->id + 1, 'count' => (int) $record->count + 1]);

       $updated = $this->save( $entity );
      }
   }
}
```

Something is wrong with this code and I cannot put my finger on but ultimately I was able to experiment with the Event System provided by the framework and the issue I am having now I want to believe is Event System related. Any help with regards to the explanation provided above would be appreciated.

Comment: The update method is basically tallyUsers method on the initial question. I just wanna know how to work with data from custom arrays and not the form in order to persist the data. For example the stats data will nevet come from a form but manually generated now how do I inject this gor persistence?